# ECDSA key recovery - floating point values

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, dsa, attack

I'm currently attempting to recover an ECDSA key.

I have $m$, $m'$ and signatures $(r, s)$, $(r', s')$, and  I know that $k$ is constant, the curve is NIST P-192 and the hash function of the. As such, I'm attempting to compute $d_A$ as shown on the wikipedia page for ECDSA.

However, after recovering $k$ (on the stage where I am computing $d_A$), I get a floating point result for $d_A$. Is this to be expected? If not, what would be the correct way of handling it?

My code, if it helps:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import hashlib
import ecdsa.util
import ecdsa
import sys
import base64

n = 6277101735386680763835789423176059013767194773182842284081
r1, s1 = ecdsa.util.sigdecode_string(open("sig1.bin", "rb").read(), n)
r2, s2 = ecdsa.util.sigdecode_string(open("sig2.bin", "rb").read(), n)
hash1 = hashlib.sha1('iSsuZJOq1FNKMuK4wm88UEkr21wgsypW'.encode('utf-8')).digest()
hash1 = ecdsa.util.string_to_number(hash1)
hash2 = hashlib.sha1('x3wqOnaetBPO66TrBaMyr3NQIDbhvK0w'.encode('utf-8')).digest()
hash2 = ecdsa.util.string_to_number(hash2)
print(r1 == r2)
#Much modulo N. Such wow.
#This totally didn't bite me in the ass for quite a while or anything <.<
top = (hash1 - hash2) % n
bottom = (s1 - s2) % n
print((top / bottom) % n)
k = int((top / bottom) % n)
print("Common constant k=0x%x" % k)
secret = (s1 * k) % n
secret = (top - hash1) % n
secret = (top / r1) % n
print(secret)
```

And the output:

```
True
6.337358414243492
Common constant k=0x6
50.34135291546233
```

Answer (score 10):

This is not correct, the private key $d_A$ must always be an integer. Your mistake is that you are doing modular division e.g. $\frac{a}{b} \text{ mod } n$ incorrectly. You cannot simply divide the integers and then reduce by the modulus. The correct way to do this is to compute the [modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $b$ i.e. $b^{-1} \text{ mod } n$ and then compute $a*b^{-1} \text{ mod } n$.